# Feature extraction using wavelets and curvelets

Tags: image-processing

I am involved in a project regarding image processing where I need to extract features of a given image. I am supposed to do that using wavelets and curvelets. But I cannot find any source where I can fully understand them. I have downloaded several journals and publications but couldn't figure out exactly how features are extracted using them.

Can someone explain how its done. Any tutorial that easily explains them is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in image processing, you musst know the existance of the library OpenCV. This is the most usefull library for image processing.
In This library there is an implementation of Haar Wavelet transform, maybe that could interest you.

For all this kine of algorithms there is another powerfull source of data. That is Matworks File Exchange. This web page is a matlab open source platform. If you don't use matlab, you can see source codes provided on this web site to understand how does wavelet and curvelet works.

For example, this project may interest you :
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33146-feature-extraction-using-multisignal-wavelet-packet-decomposition